# mongoengine enable "allowDiskUse"

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Is there an option to allow disk use in mongoengine? I could not find any resources online.

I tried

```
model.objects.aggregate(pipeline, {'allowDiskUse': True})
```

which throws:

```
Each element of the 'pipeline' array must be an object
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass it as keyword argument. Mongoengine then passes all keyword arguments further to [pymongo's aggregate method](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/3.5.1/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate)

```
model.objects.aggregate(*pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```